# Android see if Button's text contains string

Tags: android

I have a long list of radio buttons in my app.

How can I remove all buttons whose text does not contain the string "test"?

Comment: How do you create these buttons? dynamically or via xml layout?

Comment: @jeraldov I generate them in my xml layout file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could automate this:

```
ViewGroup vg= (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.your_layout);

int iter=0;
while(iter<vg.getChildCount()){
 boolean found=false;
 View rb=vg.getChildAt(iter);

 if(rb instanceof RadioButton){
  if(rb.getText().toString().contains(my_string)){//found a pattern
     vg.removeView(rb);//remove RadioButton
     found=true;
  }
 }
 if(!found) ++iter;//iterate on the views of the group if the tested view is not a RadioButton; else continue to remove

}
```

The code above doesn't deal with viewgroups inside another viewgroup (e.g. LinearLayout inside another one). I didn't test the code for the iterator and the state of the viewgroup after the call to removeView; you could check it in a console and let us know.

Comment: thanks for this answer, after a bit of tweaking it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

If you have them together in a list like List it is very simple.

```
List<RadioButton> testButtons = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();
for (RadioButton button: radioButtonList) {
    if (button.getText().toString().contains("test")) {
         testButtons.add(button);
    }
}

// assuming that they all have the same parent view
View parentView = findViewById(R.id.parentView);
for (RadioButton testButton: testButtons ) {
    parentView.removeView(button)
    // or as Evan B suggest, which is even simpler (though then it is not 'removed' from the view in the litteral sense
    testButton.setVisibility(GONE); 
}
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, but I ended up using a version of Eudhan's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Example for one button:

```
Button buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOne);

removeButtons();


public void removeButtons() {
    if (buttonOne.getText().toString() != "test") {
        buttonOne.setVisibility(GONE);
    }
}
```

Switch it up if you have an array.

Comment: You have to use `.equals()` for string comparison -- you cannot use `==` or `!=`.